# align branch labels of r plylo plot

Tags: r, plot

When plotting a phylogenetic using `ape`, tip labels are not fully aligned. Here's my code and an image to show this issue:

```
par(lty= 1)
ape::plot.phylo(phylotree, align.tip.label= T, label.offset = 1, no.margin = T, cex= .55)
```

[image]

Tip alignment can be controlled using the argument `align.tip.label= TRUE`. However, tip extensions are drawn as dashed lines even after setting par(lty=1). Is there a way to get continuous lines?
My phylotree: [tree](https://pastebin.com/EJWFq8C8)

As an aside. Font size seems to disturb perfect branch spread. Can it be increased without causing labels to clutter?

Comment: I pastebinned my phylotree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `my.plot.phylo.r` [here](https://pastebin.com/vEiPH8t9) and save it in your working directory.
Then, run the following code:

```
source("my.plot.phylo.r")
my.plot.phylo(phylotree, align.tip.label= T, label.offset = 1, 
              no.margin = T, cex= .8, font=10)
```

[image]